# Set img src from data-src attribute

Tags: jquery, drawimage, todataurl

i'm trying to set img src attribute from data-src attribute for multiple images using jquery but the code does not work. Img src does not change.

Here's a link to see my code in action.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.container figure.images').each(function(index, element){
  var thisImage = $(this);
  var canvas = thisImage.find("canvas").get(0);
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.rect(298, 0, 984, 329);
  ctx.rect(0, 329, 1280, 514);
  ctx.clip();
  img = new Image();
  img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
    var imgNew = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    thisImage.find("img").attr('src', imgNew);
  };
  img.src = thisImage.find("img").attr('data-src');
});
});
```

```css
.container figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="platform">
      <div class="container">

        <figure class="images">
          <canvas width="1280" height="843" style="display: none"></canvas>
          <img src="#" data-src="https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" alt="description" />
        </figure>

        <figure class="images">
          <canvas width="1280" height="843" style="display: none"></canvas>
          <img src="#" data-src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/bl5yz4itgbo1ggl/2.jpg" alt="description" />
        </figure>

        <figure class="images">
          <canvas width="1280" height="843" style="display: none"></canvas>
          <img src="#" data-src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/bl5yz4itgbo1ggl/2.jpg" alt="description" />
        </figure>

      </div>
    </section>
```

Thank to all and have a great day.

Comment: You code is ok, it's your URL which is wrong, dropbox is not returning an image but a webpage, if you change those urls with normal images it'll work (I'm getting some error on the load code though)

Comment: Not related to the problem, but you have two `var img` declarations. You never use the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appear to be two issues that I can see:

Dropbox is redirecting your download so that the data you're getting back is not an image, but a Dropbox HTML page.

Despite that, I wasn't able to get your canvas drawing to work (it may be possible, but it didn't work for me).  I was able to refactor it to insert a new img tag with the src set from the data-src.  This would probably be most effective if you set the data-src on the .images element and then just didn't have a default canvas or img tag.  You could do the same if you really wanted the width and height attributes as well.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.container figure.images').each(function(i, e) {
    var url = $('img', e).attr('data-src');
    $(e).append($('<img>', { 'src': url }));
  });
});
```

I also changed one of your data-src values to "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" to see that the img does work, just not with the Dropbox version.

HTH